# Push segue animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I am working in a app which is coded in Objective (only one class) and rest of the app written in Swift. In my app i have 3 storyboards and these storyboards have their `viewControllers` accordingly.

> **Issue:** Sometimes i change the `rootViewController` using beow code, the push segues animation stop working after that.

```
// constant to share globally 
let kApplicationDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
```

---

```
let controller = UIStoryboard().getControllerInstance(storyBoardName: "Autograph", identifire: "loginSuccessVC")
kApplicationDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = controller
```

Comment: Have u checked `controller` type ? Is it the same viewcontroller which u r instantiating? If not try adding `as! yourviewcontroller`

Comment: Why you are setting rootViewController? You can directly pust from your current navigation controller.

Comment: what is the type of loginSuccessVC ?

Comment: @iAnurag, sometimes storyboards are diff while navigation.

Comment: @AravindAR, storyboard.

Comment: May be the ViewCOntroller with identifier loginSuccessVC does not have NavigationController embedded to it, hence trying to push anything on top of it will not work

Comment: @vaibhav no is it an UIViewController or UINavigationController ?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh, then what if change rootview?

Comment: How is loginVC's type Storyboard?? You need to push it on viewcontroller not on storyboard.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, every storyboard's first vc is embed with NavCont.

Comment: @iAnurag, yes `loginVC` type is storyboard, i change the root view when login process is completed.

Answer (score 3):

## How to do Push Segue Transition Properly

I know it's bit late to reply for this Question! But better late than Never!

**First things First:** 
For Push transition to work properly, you have to have `UINavigationController` hosting your current ViewController as the `rootViewController`. What the heck does that mean?

**Example:**
There are two or many ViewControllers (here onwards ViewController == VC) A, B, and more. If you are currently in VC A and you want to move to VC B doing a Push (or Detail) transition on a button action in VC A, then remember your VC A has to be the RootViewController of a `UINavigationController`.

```
[  UI         ]                          [     ]            [     ]
[  Navigation ]-- RootViewController ==O>[  A  ]--- Push -->[  B  ] 
[  Controller ]                          [     ]            [     ]
```

Otherwise it doesn't work. It would appear as a Present Modally transition.

So far there are two ways I have recongised to achieve this. One is pure programmatically, the other is using StoryBoard and Code hand in hand.

**Programmatically:** 
For the ease of explaining I would embed my `UINavigationController` at the beginning of the `UIViewController` stack. In order to achieve this, we have to do a small alteration to `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions` method. It should look like following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialVCIdentifier = "AViewController" // A ViewController **
    let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: initialVCIdentifier)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC) // Assigning the A VC as the RootViewController of the NavigationController
    window?.rootViewController = nav  // Look for the *** Note bellow
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

** You have to denote the ViewController Identifier for A VC within the InterfaceBuilder. And I assume that your storyboard name is Main.storyboard. 
*** If you are not doing this for initial View controller, just present this UINavigationController as a modal VC within your VC workflow path

In the action for the button in VC A, it should look like following:

```
@IBAction func TestBtnAct(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BViewController") as UIViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

That's it! I think if you have tried it out as I've mentioned above, it should do the magic already.

**Storyboard and Code hand-in-hand:** 
This means your VC A is already being hosted by a `UINavigationController` within the storyboard design. In this case you don't need to programmatically create the `UINavigationController` and embed the VC A as the RootViewController. Just having the above Button action might be sufficient.

Hope this would be helpful to someone out there. And here is a [sample project I have done and uploaded in GitHub](https://github.com/randikachan/PushNavigationTransitionExample) for learning purposes of all of yours.

Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure! But did you try if it works for you or not?

Comment: that was an old issue, it was resolved earlier and the problem was `appDelegate` object. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you are changing the `rootViewController` try setting the `navigationController` as the root rather than the `navigationController`'s `rootViewController` .

Say you have a viewController let's name it `VCA` is the rootViewController of a `UINavigationController` `Nav1`. Then instead of making `VCA` as `rootViewController` of `kApplicationDelegate?.window?`. Try making `Nav1` as the `rootViewController` of `kApplicationDelegate?.window?`.

```
kApplicationDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = Nav1
```

The animation is not working because it may not a `push` that's occurring. The `self.navigationController` of the `ViewController` from where you are pushing might be nil.

Comment: @vaibhav does the above approach solved your problem ?

Comment: @vaibhav what's the error now? Is  the animation still not working ?

Comment: Just to confirm have to set the viewController identifier correctly of the navigationcontroller while setting the ApplicationDelegate?.window?.rootViewController  ??